# Is drawable-mdpi redundent?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi

So I read somewhere (can't remember where) that for each resolution, Android uses the next best available drawables. Like for mdpi, hdpi is used. For hdpi, xhdpi is used and so on. So if I create an app with no support for ldpi, would it be okay to delete the drawable-mdpi folder to decrease app size?

Comment: You could use xxhdpi for all resolutions, if you don't care about the quality of Android automatic scaling. But I would recommend yoou using all the drawable folders. Optimize your pngs by using optiPNG. You can also use 9 patches, where possible, and tiles (and / or gradients) for backgrounds. Also xml drawables can help in reducing the overall size.

Comment: But is what I read correct about Android using the next best available drawables?

Comment: As I said, yes. I brought the example to the limit (using one folder for all). Anyway, being possible doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: But what you're saying is if there were no mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders, Android would use xxhdpi for all devices which I understand. My question is that if there is a mdpi folder, will Android use the hdpi folder instead for a mdpi device?

Comment: NO. if there's an mdpi folder, it will use the mdpi folder. If there isn't, it will use the hdpi folder. If no hdpi folder, it will use the xhdpi folder... and so on. If the CORRECT folder is found, that one will be used. Also keep in mind images densities. Don't provide the standard, poor quality, 72 dpi graphics.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks. :)